# Placing multiple lists inside another list and displaying in a listbox in tkinter? Tried but got curly brackets in some text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make this calculator for my work involving fees for items with different categories but the listbox is where I am stuck. I am trying to display all the items in the list box using the `list_all` variable while still  applying different fee variables for the items selected for each individual list. The list comes out like [this](https://puu.sh/FX2AS/c8d191e235.png). But I am trying to put each item on a single line as well as remove the brackets placed around some of the items, I tried to find a solution but I could not find anything.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pymysql
import os
import shutil

principal = 0

interest = .015

bracket = 0

car_list = ["Car"]

list_0 = ["Jewelry"]

list_4 = ["CDs", "Movies", "Watches", "Video Games"]

list_6 = ["Camera", "Carpet tools", "Cell phones & Accesories", "Cement Hand Tools", "Coins & Money", "Clothing & Fashion", "Gift Cards",
"GPS", "Hand tools", "Harmonica", "Headphones", "Hunting", "MP3/iPod", "Machinist tools", "Meters/Testers", "Misc Auto Tools", "Nailers/Staplers",
"Office Equipment", "Paint", "Planers/Joiners", "Pool (billiards)", "Portable Audio/Video", "Sanders/Grinders", "Shoes", "Skates", "Rotozip",
"Shop Supplies" "Team Sports", "Tennis", "Toys", "Water Sports", "Winter Sports"]

list_10 = ["One of a kind", "Air Tools ", "Archery", "Art", "Band Saws", ]

list_15 = ["Televisions"]

list_25 = []

list_all = (list_4, list_6, list_10, list_15, list_25)


form = tk.Tk()
form.title("Fee Calculator")
form.geometry("500x280")

tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(form)


tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)

tab_parent.add(tab1, text="General Merch")
tab_parent.add(tab2, text="Jewelry")
tab_parent.add(tab3, text="Cars")

tab_parent.pack(expand=1, fill='both', side= 'top')


#for loop to increase width of list box
len_max = 0

for m in list_all:
    if len(m) > len_max:
        len_max = len(m)


# === WIDGETS FOR TAB ONE
listbox = Listbox(tab1, width = len_max)  

listbox.insert('end', *list_all)

listbox.pack()

#listbox categories
lbl = Label(tab1,text = "Categories") 
lbl.place(x=385,y=0) 
listbox.place(x=355, y=25)
```

Comment: ***Tried but got curly brackets in some text***: You get *curly brackets* if you try to insert a sequence, e.g. `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, into a `Tkinter`object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

```
listbox.insert('end', *list_all)
```

to:

```
for i in list_all:
    listbox.insert('end', *i)
```

---

`list_all` is a 2D `list` not a `str`.

Comment: Thanks so much, can you explain to me what the For loop does exactly in this scenario?

Comment: @NickCipriano for loop will get each element in the list, then do `*i` to unzip them. You could use `print(*i)` to see it.